# MLB Mound Visits: do pitching changes count?

Tags: rules, mlb

I have watched about 20 games this season so far, but haven't been able to glean whether changing a pitcher counts against the 6 allotted mound visits.

Can anyone clarify this definitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found, in the 2018 MLB Rule Book,

> Rule 5.10(m)(1): Mound visits without a pitching change shall be
>   limited to six per team, per nine innings. For any extra-innings
>   played, each team shall be entitled to one additional nonpitching
>   change mound visit per inning.

It looks like pitching changes are not considered Mound Visits.